# Can the original string used to generate a CTLine variable be retrieved from it?

Tags: ios, core-text

I want to test for a tap event within a Core Text `CTLineRef` variable.  I have a `CTLineRef` variable, `touchedLine`, that I have retrieved by iterating over the `CTLine`s in a frame.  Once I have found the string with a hit within its bounds, I retrieve the index of the character in the original string from `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition`.

Supposing now that the string data used to create this is not readily accessible without restructuring a portion of the code, can I retrieve the original `NSAttributedString` used to create the `CTLineRef` variable `touchedLine` from `touchedLine` itself---some sort of a `CTLineGetAttributedString` function?

Comment: The fact that it can check for the index in the original string rather than the glyphs indicates that the data are stored there, but I haven't been able to find any functions which would allow it to be extracted.  Trying to reconstruct the `NSAttributedString` from the glyph data seems treacherous as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an opaque type, `CTLine` should contain the data, but there appears to be no way to retrieve them beyond the listed functions in the Apple documentation.  So, briefly, **no, there isn't**.

(One caveat to keep in mind, which helped me solve my initial problem, is that the coordinate system which you are using for the position with `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition` may be y-flipped relative to the rest of your system---that whole Core Text thing again...)